# SFML - fluid screen update?

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate

i'm starting with sfml 2.1 but i cant find how to make the program to run fluidly

i mean, the program its working but unless i do something, like pressing a button or moving the mouse, the main loop wont run,

here is an example for my main loop code

```
     window.setFramerateLimit(30);  // set max fps to 30

     while (window.isOpen())
     {
      // this code ignores the framerate limit and doesnt runs when an event is found
         while (window.pollEvent(event))
         {
              // this code works fine but it wont run unless the user presses a key or moves the mouse
         }
     }
```

any ideas?

Comment: [That's the way it's supposed to work](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7), the code that should run "always" should be added outside of the `while (window.pollEvent(event))` loop.

Comment: You should really read the [tutorials](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/), they are essential to use SFML.

Comment: for example, if i want a sprite to move left on its own how should i do it?

Comment: @user2953006 you should read the tutorials. It does not seem to be a technical problem here, rather a lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The main loop does run, you aren't doing anything in it.

From the tutorials for 2.1:

```
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }
```

Comment: i do have code, the problem is that the screen doesnt updates even if i call the function window.display();

Comment: @user2953006 then you should post your code, we cannot help you if you don't show us what your actual problem is.

Comment: Make sure you also call window.clear(), if you need any help just post here with code snippets